# What is the simplest algorithm or pattern to continues ground/Floor

Tags: algorithm, terrain

Im beginner in 3d gaming , i have basic question not Language specific.
Say i have ground model for example terrain i modeled what is the common way to load the terrain  and use it again Or load another terrain when
the main model for example AirCraft im controlling in the game approaching its end , and i   want the player to see the terrain continue like in never ending world .

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to divide your terrain into grid and manage which grid tiles to load/unload.

Let's assume you want to have 3x3 grid all the time, with one center tile under your player, and one additional tile in each direction. Now, during every frame you check if your player has moved to another tile and if so, you load new tiles in the direction of movement and unload the tiles that are too far away. After this load/unload phase you'll still have a 3x3 grid centered over your player.

I can't make you a fine picture of it now but here's some sketch: [link](http://drawee.net/show/NPt9g)

This way you can manage quite big terrains but there're some problems you should know:

#### Tiles connection

You need to make sure that the shape of some tile at its edge is the same as the shape of its neighbor (the second tile that shares this edge) or you'll get holes in your terrain. It's quite easy if you use procedural data, like Perlin noise but it's very hard to model such meshes in 3D modelling application.

#### Grid size and scale

You can split your grid into 3x3 or even 10x10 tiles. Every tile can be few meters in size or i.e. 1km - all this depends on your specific needs. If you manage many small tiles your load/unload times will be smaller but you'll do it more often. Additionally, when you make game like a flight simulator you'll need different setup than for FPS.

#### Deferred loading

It's not a 'problem' but I've seen some interesting optimisation that I could share. It was in the Terrain Manager for the Ogre engine. It was also grid-based but much more complicated, with Quad-Trees, LOD, tile stitching, etc.

The trick was done during load/unload phase, where instead of checking `Which tiles should I load?` they checked `What is the first tile should I load?` then the Manager loaded only this one tile and returned control to the engine. In the next frame Manager did the same check and loaded 1 another tile. In this simple way you can split your loading into multiple frames, which lowers your FPS variations.